# how to add new virtual host by laravel5(routes)?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, virtualhost

I want to add a new virtual host to my domain.

For example, I have a site address of `www.example.com`

I want to show another page on the same server by creating another virtual host called `test.example.com`.

How to implement it by `Laravel5`?

`www.example.com/test` is possible, but I want to add `test.example.com`.

I'm looking at document for the laravel5(routes.php), but I can not see any related info.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at laravel's official documentation :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Host is configured by your server not by Laravel's routes. If you want to add a virtual host with subdomain, you need to add virtual host to your server config.

For example if you are using nginx with ubuntu 14
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Note: If you are using a local dev env, you can also config the vhosts on your local env, if you don't know how to do that, you can provide me which local dev env you are using, I will guide you to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so easy, but I can provide **theoretical overview Concept** how you could do it.

### DNS records

I assuming that you have a wild card `*.example.com` DNS A record (mayby also AAAA for IPv6 if requiert) that is pointing all your sub domains to your server.

### Web Server Configuration

A sub domain is something that must be configured on your Web Server (Apache, nginx, etc.). Laravel by default should not have any access to this.

#### Configure the Web server with shell/bash script

If you are able to write some shell scripts you can do it like this.

Usually **root rights are necessary** to change the Web Server configuration. I would do a **cron job** that triggers your **shell script**. If a file that is generated or updated by Laravel is dedected by the script, the script use this file to update the Web server configuration (the script should check the syntax, so that you will not end up with some issues), and reload/restart the web server afterward.

#### Use external configuration file produced by Laravel

I'm not so familiar with other Web Servers but with Apache you can include other `.conf` files in the Configuration, so this could be done es well but include some security issues also. Don't forget to reload the webserver with a cron job.

#### Only Laravel

Last but not least, if on your Server the Laravel Application it the only one, than you can send all requests on your server to Laravel and you don't have to take care about changing the Web Server configuration at all.

### Laravel Multsite

Now your new/all sub domain(s) will point to the Laravel application, but the **router do not care** about the sub domains so you have to write you **own logic** that updates the route functionality in such a way that is can handle **multsites dynamical**.

There are some multsite packages out there, that are maybe also us full for you.